# Suppose $\sum x_n$ converges (not necessarily absolutely), does $\sum \sin x_n$ necessarily converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The question is:

> If $\sum x_n$ converges, does $\sum \sin x_n$ converge?

I know that if $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum \sin x_n$ converges. My intuition is that we cannot completely abandon absolute convergence, but I am struggling to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: A small thought: $\sin(x)$ is an odd function which is increasing for small enough $x$. That means if $x_n$ is of the form $(-1)^{n}a_n$, where $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers, the sequence $\sin(x_n)$ will also be of that form (after perhaps some initial values), and so $\sum \sin(x_n)$ will also converge. In other words, you should not look for counterexamples of the form $(-1)^{n}a_n$, which are the most commonly used convergent-but-not-absolutely-convergent sequences.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret your $a_n$'s don't converge to $0.$

Comment: Absolute convergence is not necessary, it is nevertheless sufficient. Think of $x_n=(−1)^n \frac 1 n$; $\sum x_n$ does not converge absolutely, yet $\sum \sin x_n$ converges (by Leibniz's test).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's define a sequence $a_n$ three terms at a time. The $n$th grouping will look like $$\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}, \frac{-1}{2 n^{1/3}}, \frac{-1}{2n^{1/3}}.$$

Then $\sum a_n$ converges (in fact the sum is $0$). Now recall $\sin x = x - x^3/6+O(x^5).$ The $n$th grouping for $\sin a_n$ then looks like

$$\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{6n} + O(1/n^{5/3}),\frac{-1}{2n^{1/3}} + \frac{1}{48n} + O(1/n^{5/3}), \frac{-1}{2n^{1/3}} + \frac{1}{48n} + O(1/n^{5/3}).$$

The sum of those terms is $-1/(8n) + O(1/n^{5/3}).$ Therefore $\sum \sin a_n $ diverges to $-\infty.$

Comment: Thank you for answering. One small question: could you write more precisely how the sum of $O(1/n^{5/3})$ converges/doesn't affect the problem?

Comment: $\sum 1/n^{5/3} < \infty.$ If $\sum b_n$ diverges and $\sum c_n$ converges, then $\sum (b_n+c_n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, without absolute convergence this is not necessarily true. Here is a construction of a counterexample, though not a very elegant one: Let $a_n = n^{-1/3}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n - \sin a_n) \approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^3/6 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}/6 = \infty$ diverges. Define $y_{2k-1} = y_{2k} =a_k$, so that the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} y_n = a_1 -a_1 + a_2 -a_2 \pm \ldots$ obviously converges to zero. Now replace every positive term $y_n$ in this series with $2^{n}$ terms $x_k = 2^{-n} y_n$, i.e., pass to the series $a_1/2+a_1/2-a_1 + a_2/4+a_2/4+a_2/4+a_2/4-a_2 \pm \ldots$. Obviously this series still converges to zero. However, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin x_n$ will diverge. The reason for this is that the series of differences $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_n - \sin x_n)$ diverges, and the reason for that is that the positive terms of this series are $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n(2^{-n}a_n)^3 \approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty 4^{-n}n^{-1}/6 < \infty$, whereas the negative terms are $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-a_n+\sin a_n) \approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-n^{-1}/6) = -\infty$.

Comment: It is not necessary (as you say), it is nevertheless sufficient. Think of $x_n =(-1)^n \frac 1 n$; $\sum x_n$ does not converge absolutely, yet $\sum \sin x_n$ converges (by Leibniz's test).

Comment: @AlexM.: You are right, I used sloppy language, I meant that the implication is not necessarily true once you drop absolute convergence. I clarified it now.